# Securing an ajax request

Tags: ajax, security, session

i have a website that uses session cookies for security. it works fine and all, but any ajax requests right now are not secure. example being lets say a user is on a page. they can only get to this page if they are logged in with a session - so far so good. but now the ajax request they ask for is

```
ajaxpages/somepage.php?somevar=something&anothervar=something
```

if any other user decides to just go to that link themselves (without a session) they still get the same ajax output that was meant for logged in people.

so obviously im going to have to pass session data across when i send an ajax request. anyone have any tips for the best way of doing this? ive never done this before and would rather use trusted methods than make up my own.

Answer (score 5):

The ajax requests work just like any other request to your website and should return the same session cookies as the non-ajax request.  This is pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676846/do-ajax-requests-retain-php-session-info).  If you aren't getting the session cookie, perhaps something else is wrong.

Comment: i need to help, avoid duplicate comment, please refer to Rook's comments XD thanks kibbee

Answer (score 4):

Having an ajax output isn't necessarily a vulnerability.   It entirely depends on what data is being transmitted.   I am not sure what platform you are using,  but most web application development platforms have a session variable that can maintain state between requests.

What you *should*  have in place is way of marking the user as being logged in from the server side.  I php this would look like:

```
if(login($user,$password)){
   $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
}
```

Then you can check in a header file if they are allowed to access the page:

```
if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){
   header("location: http://127.0.0.1/");
   die();
}
```

(If a variable isn't set it is also false.)

There are a few things you need to keep in mind.  This is a vulnerability:

```
if(!$_COOKIE['logged_in']){
   header("location: http://127.0.0.1/");
   die();
}
```

The user can control $_COOKIE,  so they can tell you that they are logged in.

Another vulnerability:

```
if(!$_COOKIE['logged_in']){
   header("location: http://127.0.0.1/");
}
```

header()  doesn't kill the script.  In fact it still runs,  so it will still output but it won't be displayed in a browser,  you can still use netcat/telnet/wireshark to see the data.

Comment: i have a question here, i don think it is necessary to create new SO question. XD i usually use exit;. so in this case, use die better or exit better? any recommendation for me to read? about difference between die and exit. thanks. and one more, i am confused, if only check user logged in, is this vulnerable to xss? since anyone can trick the logged in user to xss site to obtain data. or i am totally wrong about xss. thanks again Rook XD

Comment: @Tian Loon  i have no idea what you are asking.  Why would there be a difference between die and exit?  Or between echo and print?  Yes,  xss can be used to hijack a session.  My post has nothing to do with xss.

Comment: oops. thanks, i just found http://stackoverflow.com/a/1795031/805373 explaining die and exit is the same. get it. thanks ROok

Answer (score 2):

Use the same security check on the pages that handle the ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

Since that is a PHP page, I don't see why you couldn't perform authentication on the PHP side. If authentication is successful, send back the data. Otherwise, send back an error message. AJAX aren't that different from any other request.

Answer (score 0):

Just let ajax carry the session cookie, there is no problem with that, but you must check if the user is logged or not at the end, and you might want to add some CSRF token for your request, just in case ...

And try to validate the referrer, so you can check if the request was sent from your website, and your website only, it's not a good practice to let user open your request url for ajax in their browser ....

And if you have query in your script, to get some data from your database or else ... don't forget to sanitize the input, and escaping the output, based on what kind of data that you need, once more just in case ...