# Understandin PHP 404 redirection related to invalid get request

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, request, http-status-code-404

Ok, am using traditional php, no frameworks, nothing, I am using simple procedural way, now my question is I was searching for a while but am not getting an answer to my question, I am not using .htaccess files as of now, but I really need to understand how 404 error works? I am having a website, where I show post's related to category, say category=php, so I pass this as a get request

```
$_GET['category'] == 'php';
```

Now currently what am doing is something like this :

```
$pocategory = $_GET['category'];

if($pocategory == 'php' || $pocategory == 'javascript') {
//Then show related posts
} else {
header('Location:404.php');
exit;
}
```

I mean I just want php and javascript as valid request's value, rest I want to redirect to 404 but am not understanding how to do it so I did this way, what if am having more than 50 categories? I cant list them all in this if condition, Inshort how to detect whether the given get request value is invalid or not..

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The solution is to get into routing, and into frameworks ^^. Also you should provide a proper `404 Not found` HTTP header in the response, not just a "not found" title in your page.

Comment: Where are the category stored ??

Comment: this is really getting over my head cuz php seems to have no way to find that whether a given get value is valid or not, if I type some random values, it just render's the page with dirty suspension errors

Comment: @Baba say for example just the 4 as of now, css, html, php and javascript, but is this the right way I guess no..

Comment: @V413HAV you mean you are not using any database for your category

Comment: nah, not as of now, I don't have any master table or it would be real easy, like fetching array out of the database and compare, but there's no way to get an invalid value, am surprised, so as far as what am doing is right I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess is the way to do this.

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php?404
```

that line will tell apache what file to load. The example above calls the main index.php script.

add something like this to the top of your index.php file:

```
$error_404 = isset($_GET["404"]) ? true : false;
```

now you can detect if you have a 404 error request. $error_404 will be true, so why not add a simple function:

```
function error_404($error_404)
{
    if($error_404 == true)
    {
       // do some error stuff here, like set headers, and some text to tell your visitor
    }
}
```

now just call your function:

```
error_404($error_404);
```

best to do that immidiatley after the get handler:

```
error_404($error_404)
$error_404 = isset($_GET["404"]) ? true : false;
```

or combine the two into one line:

```
error_404($error_404 = isset($_GET["404"]) ? true : false);
```

---

to address the question, add this to the relevant script:

```
$pocategorys_ar = array("php","javascript"); 

if (!in_array($pocategory, $pocategorys_ar)) 
{ 
    error_404(true); 
}
```

Make sure it has access to the error_404() function.

Comment: This is a custom way to tell my script if the value of get is invalid, what if user inputs any random stuff say category=blahblah?

Comment: OP wants the 404 when the user requests a category that he doesn't support, not a basic 404 redirect

Comment: Well at least that's what i understood from his question

Comment: @Seth yea you got it right, but still this is custom check, I've to pass all valid categories, is he only way :O am surprised..

Comment: OK, so I suggest adding the code above to handle standard 401. and then something like:

$pocategorys_ar = array("php,"javascript");

if (!in_array($pocategory, $pocategorys_ar))
{
    error_404(true);
}

Comment: so this all concludes that I need to state all valid categories..there's no other clean way to do

Comment: you would have to define the list to know what to do, PHP isn't psychic ;) You mention "I am using simple procedural way" are you using includes or requires? I would suggest defining the arrays and your functions in a single script that is required by the current script.

Comment: There is other way, that is loading the categories from a database. Anyway you will need to make this check so yes, it's the only option (no htacces magic possible). Also i would suggest you to make a custom page saying "This category does not exist', instead of a 404 which looks weird when it appears after changing a GET variable ;)

Comment: that's really surprising, I thought am programming like an idiot but what I was doing was right ;)

Comment: I think a database call is a bit OTT for this small list that can be defined in code. Will be quicker otherwise this is called for every page load. if you are going to go with the htaccess method, i recommend adopting a mod-rewite approach, which will route all page requests through a single PHP script, thus making your code structure cleaner and more manageable

Comment: yup you are right and that's why I've not maintained a separate table for it, thanks for your solution, will try soon, *sigh* can only give a tick :(, but I'll upvote your answer for sure :)

Comment: @V413HAV you can change your marked answer if you feel this is more useful

Answer (score 0):

You could put all categories inside an array like this:

```
$pocategories = array
(
    'php',
    'javascript'
);
if (in_array($pocategory, $pages))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    header('Location:404.php');
}
```

Another thing you could do is creating a html/php file for every category and do it like so

```
if (is_file('sites/' . $popcategory . '.php')
{
    include('sites/' . $popcategory . '.php');
}
else
{
    header('Location:404.php');
}
```

Comment: It should be `in_array` not `array_key_exists`

Comment: Sorry, changed it to `in_array`

Comment: so I guess .htaccess can do nothing over here?

Comment: Doesn't `array_key_exists` check for the index? `in_array($pocategory, $pages)` looks better to me ... oh you guys were faster :P

Comment: @V413HAV: As stated in the commends of the OP, you should also change the header to 404 as well as redirecting. Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: O've made a custom page for 404, so I redirect everything to that page using header function//

Comment: so exactly you solution was right, need to scan all the keys and if invalid than redirect, thanks anyways.. ;)