# Query SQL without refreshing the page using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Objective: Query SQL without refreshing the page using Ajax.

I have Like/Dislike buttons that function perfectly as a form and submit input, however, the form refreshes the page.

I have no clue how to make an Ajax call that connects my 'liker.php' (below) to operate within my main page via a class/id div click or button.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "liker.php",
  data: ???
  success: ???
  ...............
```

I've read some tutorials and looked for answers, but I'm still stumped.

**liker.php**:

```
//LIKE FIELD
if (isset($_POST['like'.$id])) {
  if (!in_array("$id", $like_explode)) {
    if (!in_array("$id", $dislike_explode)) {
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_like=CONCAT(pid_like,',$id') WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET likes=(likes+1) WHERE id='$id'");
    }
    else
    {
      $new_dislike_string = str_replace(",$id", '', $dislike_string);
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_dislike='$new_dislike_string' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_like=CONCAT(pid_like,',$id') WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET likes=(likes+1) WHERE id='$id'");
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET dislikes=(dislikes-1) WHERE id='$id'");
    }
  }
}
//DISLIKE FIELD
if (isset($_POST['dislike'.$id])) {
  if (!in_array("$id", $dislike_explode)) {
    if (!in_array("$id", $like_explode)) {
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_dislike=CONCAT(pid_dislike,',$id') WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET likes=(dislikes+1) WHERE id='$id'");
    }
    else
    {
      $new_like_string = str_replace(",$id", '', $like_string);
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_like='$new_like_string' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_dislike=CONCAT(pid_dislike,',$id') WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET dislikes=(dislikes+1) WHERE id='$id'");
      mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET likes=(likes-1) WHERE id='$id'");
    }
  }
}
//LIKE-DISLIKE FIELD END
```

Comment: post html snippet pleaseeee

Comment: I'm sure you can find many examples through Google, it isn't that hard. The data would be the identifier i.e if it is a like or a dislike. That can be done however you want. Using bool, ints or even a string. The success callback would be where you would simply update the amount of likes/dislikes.

Comment: Since I'm not sure how to use Ajax, I just communicate with the php like this: <form action='' method='post'><input type='submit' name='like$id' value='Like' /></form> 
:(

Comment: Thanks Script, I'll keep looking. Could you give me an example of how to write the "data" "success" part with my php file?

Comment: I'm sure someone will write an example.  I'm on mobile right now so it would be quite difficult.

Comment: Np, they have, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

i'll explain you how to use ajax with jquery. I don't understand all how it works $_POST variables, but i'll hope help you.

First use a class to know when a element like/dislike is clicked.
Second use a name to know if is a Like or Dislike.

Example for like:

```
<a href="ID" class="classForLikeOrDislike" name="like">Like</span>
```

Dislike:

```
<a href="ID" class="classForLikeOrDislike" name="dislike">Dislike</span>
```

El ajax

```
$(".classForLikeOrDislike").click(function(){

    // Get the varible ID, to send to your php
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    // Get the varible name, to send like or dislike
    var l = $(this).attr('name');


    $.post({url: "liker.php", {id: id}, success: function(result){
        // do some code here
        // here yo can see 'result' response of liker.php
        // console.log(result);
    }});

});
```

*Update change span tag by anchor tag with href .

*UPDATE to response the 'ONLY CLICK' question above*

The event variable is something that must be passed to your your anonymous function.

```
<script>
function chk(event) 
{
    // Prevent trigger submit and reload page
    event.preventDefault();
    var name=document.getElementById('clicker'); 
    $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url: "clicky.php",
          data: {clicker:1} , <--- here goes the data that you want to send to your php file,  in this case SEND $_POST['clicker'] with value 1
          cache: false,
          success: <-- When is success your request, whats you want to make (other code) maybe print 'OK'
    }); 
}
</script>


<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['clicker'])) 
  { 
      mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE items SET this='that' WHERE number='1'")
  }
?>
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot! 
Thank you!

Comment: its a bad practice to use same name for the ID attribute.

Comment: I'd say it is more than bad practice. It could cause errors  in the script when trying to manipulate DOM.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, I have one last question. 
I'm getting the ajax to query my db properly, but my echoed $likes php variable is not updating without a page reload - any ideas?

Comment: Are you actually setting  the newly  Ajaxed data in the element you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#likeButtonID").click( function()
{
     $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "liker.php",  
        data: { like: $(this).val(); },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('Ajax Success Ran');
        }
   });
});
```

Or if you have many like buttons on a page you can do a jquery loop over each of them.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

`WebMethod` let act an ajax call like a webservice, no response are processed,  class in json/xml format is returing (or nothing, just perform actions on server)

in AspNet is quite easy, try this if helps 
[PHP Equivalent to Authorized ASP.NET WebMethod (AJAX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663100/php-equivalent-to-authorized-asp-net-webmethod-ajax)

regards